# Android how to return to Main Activity without navigating backstack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm operating in a fragment, and one of the options is to delete the thing I'm looking at.  Upon confirming the delete action, I want it to just back out to the home screen, or MainActivity, and I don't want to go through the backstack, since that will attempt to traverse over the thing I just deleted.

Comment: Call MainActivity by an intent doesn't fill your needs?

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code to clear all previous stack, Launch the same main activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
// set the new task and clear flags
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(i);
```

You can also use `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity()` to clear all child activities.

Comment: As I suggested. Nice opportunity. This is called thirst for reputation, Freud explains.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider calling `finish()` or `getActivity().finish()` method to close the parent activity before you start the downstream activities.

Comment: @shizen does that work if I'm not in a different activity, and just a fragment of the main activity?

Comment: yes, you can call `getActivity().finish()` in Fragment case.

Comment: @shizen calling that just exited the application.

Comment: Exiting the app means the current activity is your apps first activity, for your case, you can call this method when your `delete action` is called. E.g. call this inside `onClickxxxx`.

Comment: But, it looks you want to return to your Main Fragment rather than the said "MainActivity" if I understand correctly. If yes, then you should use your main fragment to **replace** your current displaying fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is how to restart the Activity to circumvent data loading. The question should be why your program can't allow returning MainActivity by rolling back the stack and reload data?

Sending a new Intent can really solve your problem, but I think this may not be the most elegant approach.

Generally speaking, elegantly, your data can be shared. After deleting the data, other locations are automatically synchronized; or you are allowed to reload the data and work normally.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do so.

You can clear your `FragmentManager`'s back-stack completely.

OR just restart that activity with

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jitesh mohite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922002/8164116) has a drawback, if you'll start a new Activity, you'll end up losing all the data on the screen(if any). Launching a `Fragment` usually causes `Activity` to pause, and if re-launching an activity was the case, well why not use `Activities` is the first place?

A `FragmentManager` always consist of a list of `Fragments` in the `BackStack`

You can loop through all the Fragments and pop them out.
To clear the Fragments BackStack of a FragmentManager, you could iterate through all back stack items and call `popBackStack()`

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

But there is also more elegant solution:

```
// in my case I get the support fragment manager, it should work with the native one too
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
// this will clear the back stack and displays no animation on the screen
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```